# How to give alias to DLL in C#

Tags: c#, dll

I have added a DLL "first.dll" as reference in my C# project which in turns uses another legacy DLL "second.dll"

The "first.dll" expects "second.dll" to be in same folder. If I move "second.dll" to another folder then "first.dll" gives error.

Is there a way I can define "second.dll" path in my application?

I don't have access to source code of both DLLs.

Comment: how is this legacy-code?

Comment: See whether "Copy to output if newer" is set for both dll references

Comment: By default .Net expects to look in either the GAC or the same folder as the exe for it's dependant assemblies. Can you not set your project to 'copy to output directory' for both dlls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by picking DLL based on what program is needed. A simple IF condition did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [`<codebase>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb.aspx) in your application config (assuming second.dll is a .NET assembly)

Example from the linked article:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"
                            publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
                            culture="neutral" />
          <codeBase version="2.0.0.0"
                    href="http://www.litwareinc.com/myAssembly.dll"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
```